# Laravel 5, $errors array is always empty when using withErrors($validator)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Controller:

```php
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($data)
        ->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```

Here's the dump of `$validator->errors()` using `dd`:

[image]

BUT unfortunately in view I'm getting `$errors` as empty `ViewErrorBag` object:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can dump the errors before passing to the view, but get it empty on your view, so it's a problem with your Session. Try checking your `config/session.php` and also setting one value at one page using `Session::put()` and grabbing it back with `Session::get()` at another page to see if it is working properly.